# c++ : do while loop in my code not working properly

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

I am a newbie and got really confused with this.So basically my program takes screenshot somewhere I specify on the screen and convert it into text with tesseract OCR .The thing is I want the program to stop the loop when the outputted text ="Welcome" and continue with the rest of the code ,And I simply can't figure it out.Please help

Here is my code

```
#include <baseapi.h>
#include <allheaders.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "D:\\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    string outText="";
        do {
            system("screenshot.exe -rt 556 145 674 171");
            tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
        // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying        tessdata path
        if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Open input image with leptonica library
        Pix *image = pixRead("screenshot.png");
        api->SetImage(image);
        // Get OCR result
        outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
        cout << outText;
        Sleep(1000);
        //Cant get this to work how I expect ... it thinks outtext not equal the value even when it is read
        //and outputed correctly in the console
    } while (outText != "Welcome");
    //rest of code
    cout << "zezooooooooooooooo";
}
```

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the outputted text ever actually equals "Welcome"? A simple print statement would let you know.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something unseen in outText?  A trailing space or newline for example?

Comment: @DigitalNinja yes I did a cout statement and it outputted "Welcome"
I guess it's somethig with the tessract OCR that i don't know

Comment: @JohnHascall I thought of that and tried printing 
cout << outText<<"anytext";
and the output was anytextWelcome which was weird

Comment: So, `outText` does eventually get "Welcome". Have you tried using `strcmp` instead of `!=`?

Comment: or do a cout of `outText != "Welcome"` and ensure you're getting `false`

Comment: Like John Hascall said, there may be more in outText than just "Welcome"..  I would bet you would have at least a new line and/or carriage return.  Why don't you try something like: '    while (strncmp(outText.c_str, "Welcome", 7) != 0)'

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for helping me it worked,I checked the output buy writing to a text file and there was 2 new lines for some reason so I added \n\n

Comment: I suggest you remove non-printable characters from both ends of `outText` before doing the comparison. Preferably when you set its value. You could end up with any number of new line characters or spaces before and after the text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a do-while loop, why not just use a while loop and give the loop a bool value? Then, you'll be able to do your task and switch off when needed to by changing the bool value.

Comment: if possible can you explain with it an example so it would be easy to understand